# Finding greatest power devisor using recursion?

Tags: c++, c, recursion

The question asks me to find the greatest power devisor of (number, d) I found that the function will be like that:

```
number % d^x ==0
```

I've done so far using for loop:

```
int gratestDevisor(int num, int d){
    int p = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<=num; i++){
        //num % d^i ==0
        if( (num % (int)pow(d,i))==0 )
            p=i;
    }
    
    return p;
}
```

I've tried so much converting my code to recursion, I can't imagine how to do it and I'm totally confused with recursion. could you give me a tip please, I'm not asking you to solve it for me, just some tip on how to convert it to recursion would be fine.

Comment: Rewrite your code to not use the `pow` function (or multiplication). Then you'll have a clearer idea of how to do the recursion. (Also it'll fix a few bugs that are currently in your code.)

Comment: You should avoid using two code tags here [c++] and [c]. Moreover, it will help us to help you if you provide a [mre]

Comment: @Damien Why would you ask the OP for a minimal reproducible example? There's no bug (that they know of) that they're trying to fix.

Comment: the answer depends on whether this is C or C++, please pick one language

Comment: d must be > 1, right?

Comment: @Sneftel I am not convinced there is no bug because of the use of the `pow` function here. Moreover, having a mre will help us testing our own code

Comment: There absolutely is a bug (a few). But the OP isn't asking "how do I fix this bug", or anything of the form "what's going wrong".

Comment: I'd expect "divisor " here, not "devisor ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple method with recursion. If `d`divides `num`, you simply have to add 1 to the count, and divide `num` by `d`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int greatestDevisor(int num, int d){
    if (num%d) return 0;
    return 1 + greatestDevisor (num/d, d);
}

int main() {
    int num = 48;
    int d = 2;
    int ans = greatestDevisor (num, d);
    printf ("%d\n", ans);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please note that this code will logically enter an infinite recursion if `d` is equal to 1. *logically* because the theoretical answer *is* infinite if `d==1`.

Answer (score 1):

A recursive function consist of one (or more) base case(es) and one (or more) calls to the function itself.  The key insight is that each recursive call reduces the problem to something smaller till the base case(es) are reached.  State (like partial solutions) are either carried in arguments and return value.

You asked for a hint so I am explicitly not providing a solution.  Others have.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive version (which sucks):

```cpp
int powerDividing(int x, int y)
{
    if (x % y) return 0;
    return 1 + powerDividing(x/y, y);
}
```

Comment: Isn't op trying to find x in his formula (which is unhelpfully calls p in his function)?  powerDividing(2, 1)  returns 0.  What am I missing?